# SharePoint-2010 calendar List View Webpart to display from Monday to Sunday

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

How to make SharePoint-2010 calendar List View Webpart to display from Monday to Sunday but not Sunday to Saturday.

Answer (score 3):

Site settings, regional settings > Define your work week. 
Select the start day of the week as Monday.